# target api level (android)

Tags: android, api

I have created an application and it runs fine on devices above a certain api level, however when I run it on a phone with an API level of 7 it doesn't work correctly. It doesn't crash though. If I change the min or target api value in the manifest the application still runs and I get no errors/warnings in eclipse. So my question is how am I supposed to tell what API level to use without installing every single android API, creating an emulator and seeing if it runs correctly. the erro happens when I use the following code 
when I use the following code:

```
 ' cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             cal.set(year, month, day, hour,minute);
            current time

             intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
             intent.putExtra("vns", 1);


             sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent,
             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            // Get the AlarmManager service
             am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
             am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);'
```

it does not correctly set an event instead it does nothing

Comment: Could ou describe what are the problems you encounter on lower API ?

Answer (score 0):

When supporting multiple API's, always code using the lowest one.

To find out what you should not use:

For the Class/Method about which you have doubt, notice the documentation popup, It tells minimum API level , e.g. **Since: API Level 1**

Go to [Android developer API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)  , search for a package, then select API level, unsupported package members will be marked.

Comment: In fact, you’ll want to test your code on the minimum API **and** on the target API. The latter is because many Android releases introduce additional restrictions but apps targeting older APIs are exempt from them. If your code runs on both these versions, chances are it will also run on those in between—though this is not a 100% guarantee. If your code has any conditionals based on the API level, it is also recommended to test the two API levels right before and after the “border”.